# Can't connect web server from a port-forward.

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, iptables, webserver

I have a web-server that is running fine and anyone on My LAN can connect with it's local I.P. We recently switch to this server from a  previous server running Rhel5 our current server is running Rhel7. We have a Port forward in place When someone hit's our companies external I.P. it will forward them to the local server I.P. and port 8080. This worked fine on our last server but we are unable to connect with our current server. 
here are my iptables:

```
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_public (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:rfb:5903 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:webcache ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:intermapper ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5903 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:webcache ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5901 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:intermapper ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Has the port forwarding rule been updated on the firewall to point to your new server?

Comment: @MarkoPolo thanks for your response. The I.P. is the same as the last server. I think I new to change the default gateway of my server but I don't know how.